# Running a JavaFX application to a web browser and connecting back to a server

Tags: javafx

we are embedding an application into a browser and it needs to connects to a server while running on a web browser (on local host). Is there any way I can do this I am having difficult and have not seen any resources online

Comment: Please show what you've already tried.

Comment: I tried putting all dependencies into the jar files and using our UNIX system. and updating using our shell

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As your question stands, it's not really possible to answer it; it is far too broad and there are far too many technologies you could be using that fall under the description you have given of the problem. It will probably help you to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask; then edit your question and provide more details about what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and the ways in which it doesn't behave as you expect/want it to.